# How to shorten code

Tags: java, android

I am making a calculator and below is my code. I was wondering is there any way to shorten the code, I have 18 buttons and I have to write 50 lines of code just to take reference from XML and add click listener to it

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

String SelectedOpertator;
int num1, num2, result;

EditText input;
Button b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6 ,b7, b8, b9, b0, bdot;
Button bc, bs, bd, bp, bmi, bm, be;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);
    b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b5);
    b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b6);
    b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b7);
    b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b8);
    b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);
    b0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b0);
    bdot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bdot);

    bc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bc);
    bs = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bs);
    bd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bd);
    bp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bp);
    bmi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bmi);
    bm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bm);
    be = (Button) findViewById(R.id.be);

    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    b4.setOnClickListener(this);
    b5.setOnClickListener(this);
    b6.setOnClickListener(this);
    b7.setOnClickListener(this);
    b8.setOnClickListener(this);
    b9.setOnClickListener(this);
    b0.setOnClickListener(this);
    bdot.setOnClickListener(this);
    bc.setOnClickListener(this);
    bs.setOnClickListener(this);
    bd.setOnClickListener(this);
    bp.setOnClickListener(this);
    bmi.setOnClickListener(this);
    bm.setOnClickListener(this);
    be.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

Is there any other way to write this code in shorter way?

Comment: I think you can use a loop

Comment: I don't think so. Just split those findingview and setting onclicklistener to some methods for better code formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a method to do the `findViewById` and `setOnClickListener`, you can reduce the lines for each button from two to one:

```
private Button findAndSetClickListener(int id) {
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(id);
  button.setOnClickListener(this);
  return button;
}
```

Then:

```
b1 = findAndSetClickListener(R.id.b1);
// etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int ids[] = new int[] {R.id.b1, R.id.b2, R.id.b3, R.id.b4, R.id.b5, R.id.b6, R.id.b7, R.id.b8, R.id.b9, R.id.b0}

for(int i = 0; i < ids.length, i += 1){
    findViewById(ids[i]).setOnClickListener(this); 
}
```

---

There's no need for storing reference to each button as class members. In the `onClick` listener we can determine which button was clicked.

```
public onClick(View v){
    int number = Arrays.asList(ids).indexOf(v.getId()) + 1;
    // Button 'number' was clicked
}
```

Comment: This presupposes that the references to the buttons are not required outside the `onCreate` method.

Comment: This is good! But isn't him losing the button reference this way? What if he need to call some other function on the buttons?

Comment: if you want to keep the button reference, use the same technique with button. `Button [] buttons = new Button{b1, b2, ...};` and them in the loop add `buttons[i] = (Button) findViewById(ids[i])`.

Comment: @sonic that starts to get hard to maintain because you have to keep the two arrays in sync if you add/remove any elements.

Comment: @AndyTurner i agree with you. But if the UI doesn't change a lot it will be good. Another solution can be to have a strong convetion about the name of the field for each button and his id (`Button b1` has id `R.id.b1`) and use reflection. Instead of having two array, you will only have on string array with the name of the filed/id. You can then retrieve both field from `R.id` and `this` with the name. However i think it will be too painful.

Comment: @sonic code which doesn't change a lot, in a sense, needs to be easiest to maintain: if you are changing it all the time, you remember that you need to update both arrays, whereas you might well forget if you change it infrequently. The "paired array" approach is basically the transpose of what ParkerHalo and I suggest (i.e. the code takes up space horizontally, rather than vertically). One advantage of writing it vertically is that the pairs of corresponding items are checked by the compiler (there have to be the same number in each list), and adding/removing a pair in the middle is easy.

Answer (score 1):

try this type code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements     View.OnClickListener {

String SelectedOpertator;
int num1, num2, result;

EditText input;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);    


     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b1)).setOnClickListener(this);
     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b2)).setOnClickListener(this);
     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b3)).setOnClickListener(this);
     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b4)).setOnClickListener(this);
     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b5)).setOnClickListener(this);
     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b6)).setOnClickListener(this);
     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b7)).setOnClickListener(this);
     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b8)).setOnClickListener(this); 
     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b9)).setOnClickListener(this);
     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.b0)).setOnClickListener(this);

     ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bdot)).setOnClickListener(this);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bc)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bs)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bp)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bmi)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.bm)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.be)).setOnClickListener(this);




}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to show here? Code dumps without any explanation are not useful.

Comment: Casting `((Button) findViewById(R.id.b1)).setOnClickListener(this);` to `Button` is not required

Answer (score 1):

You could write an array where you store the views.

So that you can do something like

```
for (View v : array.getView()) {
    v.setOnClickListener(this)
}
```

I think the actual `findViewById` would be a little more complicated to simplify

Answer (score 1):

You could shorten it at about 50% (and make it a lot more readable) with a private method:

```
private Button getButtonWithListener(int id) {
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(id);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    return btn;
}
```

and call this at every button: (saves you the setOnClickListener)

```
b1 = getButtonWithListener(R.id.b1);
b2 = getButtonWithListener(R.id.b2);
b3 = getButtonWithListener(R.id.b3);
b4 = getButtonWithListener(R.id.b4);
b5 = getButtonWithListener(R.id.b5);
b6 = getButtonWithListener(R.id.b6);
b7 = getButtonWithListener(R.id.b7);
b8 = getButtonWithListener(R.id.b8);
b9 = getButtonWithListener(R.id.b9);
b0 = getButtonWithListener(R.id.b0);
bdot = getButtonWithListener(R.id.bdot);

bc = getButtonWithListener(R.id.bc);
bs = getButtonWithListener(R.id.bs);
bd = getButtonWithListener(R.id.bd);
bp = getButtonWithListener(R.id.bp);
bmi = getButtonWithListener(R.id.bmi);
bm = getButtonWithListener(R.id.bm);
be = getButtonWithListener(R.id.be);
```

This way you're not losing the reference to the button. If you need those references to the buttons it won't become much shorter. If you don't need them, then there are some excellent possibilities in the other answers here!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to shorten the button code, Use View's in OnClick() with help of switch statement.

**In your XML Layout:**

Create the number of buttons that you want with different button id. But use same method name for all button's onClick attribute. **Eg:**  **android:onClick="submitBTN"** used for all buttons.

**In your MainActivity:**

Implement that method name to perform different operations using switch statement

```
    public void submitBTN(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnClick1:    // Code of button 1 Click
            break;
        case R.id.btnClick2:    // Code of button 2 Click
            break;
        case R.id.btnClick3:     // Code of button 3 Click
            break;
        case R.id.btnClickn:    // Code of Button n Click
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using butter knife library. You can use syntax like:

```
@Onclick({R.id.b1, R.id.b2...｝）
public void handleClick(Button  btn){
         // handle click event here
}
```